# 403-forbidden error running sharepoint online search rest api from c# console appl

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, error, sharepoint-search, console-application

I am trying to run below SharePoint Online Search REST API in C# console application but receiving error.

```
https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/scr/_api/search/query?querytext=%27scStatusOWSCHCS=Expired%27
```

The account/username I am using is already a global admin and SharePoint site collection admin and owner.

I am receiving 403 Forbidden error. Can someone suggest what permissions/authorization am I missing?

Can someone give me working example reference?  I am using GET method.

I am referring to example in below thread:

[I want to implement SharePoint document search using C# api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59470250/i-want-to-implement-sharepoint-document-search-using-c-sharp-api)

Comment: Did you enable Multi-factor authentication (MFA) for your environement?

Comment: Yes. We do have . But i am using a service account. Not my personal account.